# Appium inspector is not launching for Android

Tags: android, mobile, automated-tests, appium, inspector

I followed each and every step given in http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-appium--cms-23861

Appium app has started fine with `appium $`

Please see [image: Android Settings]

When I click **Launch** Button see output in image below
[image: Output]

On clicking Appium inspector button, this error is displayed.
[image]

Please help me to figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: android uiautomator does better job than appium inspector . I would suggest to use uiautomator

Comment: @ShekharSwami Your suggestion worked. I want to make your answer as accepted.

Comment: very poorly posted question , if you had followed all the instructions then you would have filled up all the details in the Appium UI. No proper instruction were followed . Pls post your Appium logs to help you further

Comment: This Appium Inspector UI is not supported anymore. Go to https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/ to get our new officially supported UI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

android uiautomator does better job than appium inspector . I would suggest to use uiautomator . @Farhat Naz Biya now you can accept this ans . cheers :)

Comment: No longer supported for Android

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use

> uiautomatorviewer

which comes with android sdk tools.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `Package` for your application there. You would have to provide that parameter through the UI in case you want to use the appium inspector independently.

Comment: when I choose default package from appium and click launch button, outout is like 
`Launching Appium with command: export ANDROID_HOME="/Users
...
"0.0.0.0" --robot-port "4723" --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "5.0.1" --app "/Users/mac/Downloads/APPIUM_INTRO-master/app/AUT.apk" --avd "Nexus_5_API_21" --app-pkg "com.example.mkim.aut" --app-activity "com.example.mkim.aut.LoginActivity" --app-wait-package "com.example.mkim.aut" --app-wait-activity "com.example.mkim.aut.SuccessfulLogin" --device-name "" --intent-flags "0x10200000"
`

Comment: it would be good to have the relevant appium logs pasted in the question. + i hope you have a device connected

Comment: export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk"; '/usr/local/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --port "4726" --command-timeout "7200" --debug-log-spacing --robot-address "0.0.0.0" --robot-port "4723" --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "5.0.1" --app "/Users/mac/Downloads/APPIUM_INTRO-master/app/AUT.apk" --avd "Nexus_5_API_21" --app-pkg "com.example.mkim.aut" --app-activity "com.example.mkim.aut.LoginActivity" --app-wait-package "com.example.mkim.aut" --app-wait-activity "com.example.mkim.aut.SuccessfulLogin" --device-name "" --intent-flags "0x10200000"

Comment: no device connected. Specifying emulator name {Nexus_5_API_21} in android settings.

Comment: @FarhatNazBiya do you have an AVD with same name? otherwise somewhere your appium logs might be reading something similar to `error: Unable to start Emulator: emulator: ERROR:`

Comment: Yes I have added  added AVD  in android studio with the name `Nexus 5 API 21`

Answer (score 1):

You have to give package name and activity name that you are looking to launch the app in appium.

Comment: In android settings only option available in package name drop down is `com.example.mkim.aut`

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting long enough for the Appium server to start. You need to see

```
info: Welcome to Appium v.1.4.13 etc
info: -> GET /wd/hub/status {}
```

Then you can click the inspector button.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use ***UI Automator viewer*** instead of Appium Inspector.

**Pre-requisites :-**
Connect your android device with the system or start an emulator on which you wants to find the object of the elements.

**Steps to Launch UI Automator :-**

1. Go to Android SDK location
2. Click on Tools
3. Click on "uiautomatorviewer"

It will launch a new pop-up window. Click on "Green icon" on the left side of the screen. It will load the connected mobile device preview.

Answer (score 1):

SDK --> Tools --> UI Automator. This will be more helpful than inspector in Appium.

Keep the app in a path which doesn't contain space or special characters on the foldername or app name. Then select the app path.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the "Pre-launch with Application" checkbox under Settings.  That way the Android Emulator will launch with your app installed and loaded.  Once the Android Emulator is running, then try opening the Appium Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the appium logs please. Is your error likes "error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a connected Android device."?

By looking at your images, 
I think you checked deviceName capability, but you did't gave a name for it. If you share appium logs I can give a direct answer.

BTW for Android app automation, I prefer to use "uiautomatorviewer". It is fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your Appium server, yo have to wait some time until all your settings are loaded.
Please refer snapshot below:

[image]

Now click on Inspector, it will start.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait for the appium start with all the configuration.once you get status code 200(in green color). then press inspector. image inspector will be launch.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you have checked Device Name but you have left that text field empty. So please write some text in that field e.g. TestDevice
Please see here:
[image: Android Device Name]

Also, see if you have added correct path into Android SDK Path Please see example: [image: ANDROID SDK PATH]

Answer (score 0):

The Inspector won't work unless you Launch the server .
1.Launch the server
2.Run the test
3. Wait for the screen you want to inspect
4.Then Start inspector.
 You can also refresh the page in inspector depending the screen you need .

Answer (score 0):

First start the server (from command line or GUI),

if you're using command line.. wait for this line :
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

if you're using GUI, you'll see all device capabilities are loaded, then wait for the same line as in command line : 
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

Then, you can use the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

1. specify the path.
2. start the server with correct app_path and package value.
3. wait for the server to start and than click the inspector button

Answer (score 0):

wait for the appium start with the given configuration. Launch the app with appium once and then press inspector. inspector will be launch.

Or Use uiautomatorviewer tool present in Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

i had a same issue i solved it by setting the package name which is in the cradle build and the LaunchActivity name with full package name then it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also use AndroidViewClient tools - `dump` and `culebra` to find out the IDs. It is helpful in places where you don't have a UI (for example, if you are running on a server version of Ubuntu).